# Adobe DTM Form submission - capturing input value

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

I'm trying to capture the value being submitted by the form code below whether the enter button or actual submit button is clicked. Currently I have an event based rule:

```
Event Type: submit
Element Tag or Selector: form
id = inputCuratedSearch
```

But the rule is not firing?

```
<form method="post" action="/small-business.html" id="form1">
<li class="nav-utility-item hovering" id="curatedSearch">
<a href="#" id="lnkSearch" class="nav-utility-link search2015 curatedSearch2016" aria-expanded="false">search</a>
<div id="containerCuratedSearch" class="curatedContainer searchOpen" aria-hidden="true" style="display: block;">
<input id="inputCuratedSearch" class="ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" list="data-json" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off">
  <input id="blockInput" class="" style="display: none">
    <button id="btnCuratedSearch"></button>
```

Not sure what I did wrong and also how do I capture the value in the input field?

Comment: I also tried using input#inputCuratedSearch in the Element Tag or Selector field but that didn't work either.

Comment: If I change the event type to "focus" the rule fires but won't fire when changed to submit? Not sure why and not sure how to capture input value?

Comment: according to your posted code, the form id is `form1` so your rule condition should point to that, because it is the whole form that is being submitted, not the individual input. beyond that, if it still doesn't work, then you may have other code on the page stopping the form submit from propagating / preventing default submit. Perhaps some other custom js on your page that actually handles form submission. Can't really say w/out looking at the page.